# How to calculation 'lifetime' of inflation model

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, cosmological-inflation

How to calculate the 'lifetime' of an inflation model? How are calculations performed with the help of a 
Hubble parameter for an inflation model?

Comment: You must specify an inflation potential, initial field value, and initial field velocity. Then you can calculate the inflationary trajectory, including the duration of inflation, using the Friedmann equations.

Answer (score 1):

By 'lifetime', I'm going to assume you mean 'duration'.  The duration of inflation is typically given in terms of the number of e-folds, $N$, of expansion that occur under an inflationary equation of state, where $dN = -Hdt$, where $H$ is the Hubble parameter.  It is convenient to rewrite this quantity in terms of the scalar field,$$dN = - \frac{H}{\dot{\phi}}\,d\phi.$$

The Hubble parameter is given by the Friedmann equation, $$H^2 = \frac{8\pi}{3m_{\rm Pl}^2}\rho,$$ where the energy density is $\rho = \dot{\phi}^2/2 + V$ and the field evolution is governed by the Klein-Gordon equation, $$\ddot{\phi} + 3H\dot{\phi} + V' = 0.$$

Given a potential, $V(\phi)$, an initial field velocity, $\dot{\phi}_0$, and initial field value, $\phi_0$, this is all you need to solve for the number of e-folds of expansion that occur as the field evolves in the potential.

A helpful approximation is the slow-roll limit, for which $$H^2 \simeq \frac{8\pi}{3m_{\rm Pl}^2} V$$ and $$3H\dot{\phi} \simeq -V'.$$ In this limit, the inflaton potential energy dominates over its kinetic, and the evolution of the field is governed by the Hubble drag. Then, the expression for $dN$ simplifies considerably,
$$dN = \frac{8\pi}{m_{\rm Pl}^2}\frac{V}{V'}\,d\phi.$$  You might be able to perform the resulting integral analytically, depending on the form of $V(\phi)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me. Another question that has arisen for me. we know universe cannot get stuck in a local minimum for V  for an infinite amount of time. So how is calculated the dS lifetime or metastable dS life time ?

Comment: In general, the lifetime of a metastable state in semiclassical gravity goes as $\Gamma \sim e^{-B}$, where $B = S_E(\phi) - S_E(\phi_+)$, where $S_E$ is the Euclidean action and $\phi_+$ is the false vacuum (local minimum).  If the potential barrier isn't very large (thin wall approx) then $B \approx 2\pi^2 \sigma/H^3$ where $\sigma$ characterizes the barrier.